# Bundle extra Returns Nothing ,Unable to pass data between Activity and Service

Tags: java, android

Please, I have a problem passing values from an activity to a service. In my activity I have text view fields with values and I am passing them to a service class like is

```
                 intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SaveService.class);                             
         intent.putExtra("lt",latituteField.getText().toString().trim() );                  
         intent.putExtra("lg",longitudeField.getText().toString().trim()); 
         intent.putExtra("sp",SpeedField.getText().toString().trim());
         intent.putExtra("alt",AltitudeField.getText().toString().trim());
         intent.putExtra("ltDMS",lbllatitude.getText().toString().trim());
             intent.putExtra("lgDMS",lbllongitude.getText().toString().trim());
         intent.putExtra("Add",AddressLabel.getText().toString().trim());
         intent.putExtra("TNum",TNumber);
```

This code is in my MainActivityClass and now in my service class I have this

```
  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      if (extras != null)
      LAT= extras.getString("lt");
     LNGT= extras.getString("lg");
      SPEED= extras.getString("sp");
      ALT= extras.getString("alt");
      LATDMS= extras.getString("ltDMS");
      LONGDMS= extras.getString("lgDMS");
      ADD= extras.getString("Add");
      TNUM= extras.getString("TNum");


startDate = new Date();
displayToast("Service started at: " + startDate);
new Save().execute("http://192.168.30.1/androidphp/SaveValues.php");

//Here we want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
//stopped, so return sticky

return START_STICKY;

}
```

Whenever I  run the code it give me null reference exception at

```
LNGT= extras.getString("lg");
```

and when I comment that part out , It move to the next and next till the end. When I comment all out except the first one

```
 LAT= extras.getString("lt");
```

it doesn't give me that error but it doesn't have any value. I don't know what I am missing , Am I not passing the data well or it cannot pass multiple data to service like this . Please help me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing a bundle to your intent then you are getting a bundle from your reciever intent which will of course catch an exception of NPE...

**solution:**

instead of getting it from the bundle try getting it from the intent

**example:**

```
intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: Please, it is still returning no value after changing it to your suggestion

Comment: Please , I have tried to applied your suggestions but the problem still persist. Is there something else I am missing

Answer (score 0):

It gives NPE because you forgot to wrap if-branch with {}.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    LAT= extras.getString("lt"); //if no {}, then only this line is in the if-block.
    LNGT= extras.getString("lg");
    SPEED= extras.getString("sp");
    ALT= extras.getString("alt");
    LATDMS= extras.getString("ltDMS");
    LONGDMS= extras.getString("lgDMS");
    ADD= extras.getString("Add");
    TNUM= extras.getString("TNum");
}
```

Comment: public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   if (extras != null)
   {
   LAT= extras.getString("lt");
  LNGT= extras.getString("lg");
   SPEED= extras.getString("sp");
   ALT= extras.getString("alt");
   LATDMS= extras.getString("ltDMS");
   LONGDMS= extras.getString("lgDMS");
   ADD= extras.getString("Add");
   TNUM= extras.getString("TNum");
  
   }
startDate = new Date();

new Save().execute("http://192.168.30.1/androidphp/SaveValues.php");

return START_STICKY;
}

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Does it still throws NPE?

Comment: No, It does not give me any exception now, but the values in the variables are all Null. I can not get the values from the Activity to the service

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now , I modified the code and used a bundle to pass the values instead using the intent

```
 Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, SaveService.class);
                  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();             
                  bundle.putString("lt",latituteField.getText().toString().trim() );                    
                  bundle.putString("lg",longitudeField.getText().toString().trim()); 
                  bundle.putString("sp",SpeedField.getText().toString().trim());
                  bundle.putString("alt",AltitudeField.getText().toString().trim());
                  bundle.putString("ltDMS",lbllatitude.getText().toString().trim());
                  bundle.putString("lgDMS",lbllongitude.getText().toString().trim());
                  bundle.putString("Add",AddressLabel.getText().toString().trim());
                  bundle.putString("TNum",TNumber);
                  intent.putExtras(bundle);              
                  startService(intent);
```

So i have this code in my MainActivity and in my Service.class, I receive the data like this

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      if (bundle != null)
      {
      LAT= (String)bundle.getString("lt");  
      LNGT= (String)bundle.getString("lg");
      SPEED= (String)bundle.getString("sp");
      ALT= (String)bundle.getString("alt");
      LATDMS=(String)bundle.getString("ltDMS");
      LONGDMS= (String)bundle.getString("lgDMS");
      ADD= (String)bundle.getString("Add");
      TNUM= (String)bundle.getString("TNum");

      }
```

I now I am getting the values passed from my MainActivity to the service, very well. Thank you everyone for your support and clues. I really appreciate it.